# Enable brightness/volume popup for keyboard backlight, numlock, caps, et al

Tags: sound, keyboard, brightness, backlight

In the following figure you can see a popup which is displayed whenever I (de)activate the microphone. A similar popup is displayed when changing the screen brightness of my laptop or when changing the overall system speaker volume. [image]

My question is how I can enable the same popup on several other things, e.g. when changing the keyboard backlight (which has 2 levels + off), or when (de)activating numlock, capslock, fn lock and similar other things.